# seaborn missing axes points markers

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some histograms with seaboorn. But no matter what type of graph I use, it's missing axes points markers. So I can see the number but not any indicator of its precise position on an axis.

Here's an example of one of my plots:

Code:

```
with sb.plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=1.2):
    sb.set_style("white")
    plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,5))
    sb.histplot(x=melted["Tanimoto coefficient"], binwidth=0.05, binrange=[0,1], hue=melted["Type"], palette="bright", hue_order=["Fragments", "Molecules"])
```

Plot:

[image]

What I would like is for axes to look like this:
[image]

Any way to do this? Or is seaborn not including the markers by default for a reason?

Comment: `import seaborn as sns` and `sns.set_style("ticks")`?

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: See also [Controlling figure aesthetics](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html)